# Variable parameter lists: possibility to collect them in variable?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

when a C-function defines a variable parameter list like

```
myfunc(int *i,...);
```

I can call it (according to it's correct usage) e.g. with

```
myfunc(&i,1,"hello",2,42);
```

or

```
myfunc(&i,"fish",13,33,"haktar",2,42);
```

But is there also a possibility to collect these parameter data in a list and then hand it over to the function afterwards? Means is there a variable type available that allows something like this (pseudocode):

```
arg_list list;

list.add("fish");
list.add(13);
list.add(33);
list.add("haktar");
myfunc(&i,list);
```

If yes: how can this be done exactly? Thanks!

Edit: To clarify this a bit: myfunc(int *i,...) is a given function protoype which can't be modified, means I have to deal with the "..." argument part using a suitable (va_arg-like?) data type, I can't use a simple array/chained list/other own data type there.

Comment: Why dont you use an array??

Comment: Akansha: An array of what data type when int and char[] can be mixed?

Comment: Your first function, `myfunc(int *i, ...)` cannot sensibly be used with C variadic arguments. How does the function know which argument is a string and which is a number. (`printf` and `scanf` know because of the format specifiers in the format string.) Your list approach looks more promising, but you will have to create a variant data type that can store numbers and strings and that will always know of which type it is.

Comment: Does the first argument defines the number of arguments followed? And are the type of the followed arguments in the following pattern: string, int, int, string, int, int, ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the correct answer seems to be: it is not possible, because all these va_* thingies used for variable arguments are no functions or datatypes but macros which are resolved by preprocessor. So this whole stuff seems to be possible with static code only, nothing that changes during runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly call a function that expects a variable argument list that way. Instead you could change the function to receive for example an array of items containing unions of allowed argument types:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

enum arg_type { ARG_TYPE_INTEGER, ARG_TYPE_STRING };

struct arg {
    enum arg_type type;
    union {
        int integer;
        const char *string;
    };
};


static void myfunc(size_t length, struct arg list[length])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("argument %zu: ", i);
        switch (list[i].type) {
            case ARG_TYPE_INTEGER: printf("integer: %d", list[i].integer); break;
            case ARG_TYPE_STRING: printf("string: %s", list[i].string); break;
        }
        puts("");
    }
}


int main()
{
    struct arg list[] = {
        { .type = ARG_TYPE_STRING, .string = "fish" },
        { .type = ARG_TYPE_INTEGER, .integer = 13 },
        { .type = ARG_TYPE_INTEGER, .integer = 33 },
        { .type = ARG_TYPE_STRING, .string = "haktar" }
    };

    myfunc(sizeof list / sizeof *list, list);
}
```

(Note that this uses C11 language features; you may need to enable C11 support in your compiler, e.g. using the `-std=c11` option for clang or gcc)

Comment: please see the edit in my posting above - I CAN NOT change the function, I don't have access to it

Answer (score 0):

What you suggest is that your function takes some sort of struct to be filled, and this struct be handed over to another function.

I hope this helps :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void GetParams(struct list *ptr,char *string1,int a,int b,char *string2);

void myfunc(int *i,struct list List);

struct list
{
char* string1;

int a;

int b;

char* string2;
};

int main(void)
{
int i;

list List;

GetParams(&List,"fish",13,33,"haktar");

myfunc(&i,List);


}

void GetParams(struct list *ptr,char *string1,int a,int b,char *string2)
{
ptr->string1 = string1;

ptr->a = a;

ptr->b = b;

ptr->string2 = string2;
}

void myfunc(int *i,struct list List)
{
*i = 1;
// ...
printf("i : %d\n",*i);

printf("%s\n",List.string1);
printf("%d\n",List.a);
printf("%d\n",List.b);
printf("%s\n",List.string2);
}
```

Comment: machine_1: thanks for your suggestion but that's something I wanted to avoid. In ANSI-C there already exist some va_arg-like data types that are somehow able to handle different data and I'd prefer to use them. But the question is, if it is really possible to use them from outside or only as a function parameter...

Comment: The va_arg type from stdarg.h can only be used to pass a list of arguments that _are_ already arguments from a function call. Think of it as a pointer to  some place on the stack where arguments were stored when a function was called.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you created your list a bit like this

```
typedef struct arg_list {
    void *data;
    struct arg_list *next;
}
```

You would need to create a function that adds your parameters to the list.

```
void list_add(arg_list **list, void *data)
{
    arg_list *elem;

    elem = malloc(sizeof(arg_list)); // check what malloc returns

    elem->data = data;
    elem->next = *list;
    *list = elem;
}
```

This is a "sketch", don't forget to allocate your data!
This way, your data is added to the start of the list!

You can add stuff like this:

```
list_add(&list, "Hello");
list_add(&list, 42);
```

Edit: I forgot to tell you how to use it.

You can use it via `list->data` and `list->next` to go to the next element.

This is called a linked list.

Comment: nice idea but I can't hand over this list to a parameter of type "..." as described in my posting

Comment: You sure you want to use variable lists? because it's the same thing. You can still hand the list you created to a function like this `func(&i, list)` and use your list with all the data in it

Comment: I definitively HAVE to use a variable argument list because the API that needs to be used here expects this

Comment: Oh ok. Well then you should [read this](http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/stdarg.3.html)

Comment: The problem with this code is the same as with the original argument lists: You need to know which piece of data is of which type. (Here, this could be solved by adding a type field to the node structure like in the variant type poposed by dpi.)